# Executable not found when running docker container

Tags: docker

I am trying to dockerize a `cpp` application and after i build the image in docker and run it i get an error.
**Error**:
 `/bin/sh: 1:home/simple/Main: not found`

**main.cpp**

```
 #include<iostream>

 int main(){
 std::cout<<"Hellow World";
 return 0;
 }
```

I compile this with : `g++ -o Main main.cpp`

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN mkdir -p /home/simple
COPY . /home/simple
CMD home/simple/Main
```

**Docker commands**

`docker build -t myapp .`
 `docker run myapp`

**P.S**  I have followed this guide :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kejsVBoP4kE
How can it not find the `executable` since it it is in the same folder with the `Dockerfile`.When i run `COPY . /home/simple` could it somehow happen to copy only `1/2` of the files?

**P.S.2** After setting the `ENTRYPOINT ["ls","-l","/home/simple/"]` the returned files were `0`.
It seems that the `ADD/COPY . /home/simple/` does not work.No files are copied.

Comment: Maybe `CMD /home/simple/Main` ?

Comment: I have tried.It still reports the same error.

Comment: Better show us the contents of your folder.

Comment: Ok so i found the problem.Apparently the `COPY` command does not work.I have used as an entrypoint `ENTRYPOINT ["ls","-l","/home/simple/"]` and there are no files in.I have also tried the `ADD src dest` version and still it does not copy anything in the image.

Comment: Maybe add `WORKDIR /home/simple`. Or your current path is wrong.

Comment: The problem lies in selecting the local filesystem's current folder.It seems `COPY/ADD  .   /home/simple/` does not copy the contents to the image.

Comment: This shouldn't happen if all parameters are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the forward slash infront of the word home, on the last line.
Change: CMD home/simple/Main
To: CMD /home/simple/Main

Comment: I added the slash as another user pointed out in a comment.It still prints the same error.

Comment: Is the MODE correct on the executable?

Maybe before trying to run it, try adding chmod 0755 /home/simple/Main